# try and except function error in a discord bot

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I am unable to use the try function in my discord bot. Instead of moving to the except function an error message is printed in the terminal

```
@client.command()
async def new(ctx, *, players):
    try:
        data = Team()
        data_output = data.team(players)
        team1 = data_output[0]
        team2 = data_output[1]
        response = "Team 1"
        response2 = "Team 2"
        
        await ctx.send(f'''{response} -- {team1}
{response2} -- {team2}''')

    except:
        await ctx.send('''Please use the command in the correct format
First the command by "/new"
and then the name of the players without and thing between
other than spaces

Example: /new p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6''')
```

The Output

```
File "C:\Users\animi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 542, in transform   
    raise MissingRequiredArgument(param)
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: players is a required argument that is missing.
```

Here rather than printing the error report, it was supposed to move to the except statement but it did not.

Could someone please suggest me what am I supposed to do

Comment: What is the function `Team()`?

Comment: Tip: You can use `\n` for newlines instead of actually putting in a new line. In other words, you can write this `await ctx.send(f'{response} -- {team1}\n{response2} -- {team2}')` and it'll give you the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For errors thrown by the discord.py library you have to use an error handler

```py
@client.command()
async def new(ctx, *, players):
    # Your code here


@new.error # <- the name of the command + .error
async def new_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send("Please use the command in the correct format")
```

Reference:

- [Error Handling](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html?highlight=handling%20errors#error-handling)

Answer (score 0):

Normally, for error handling, you would use an [Error Handler](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html?highlight=handling%20errors#error-handling). This can be in the form of a decorator or in the global event `on_command_error()`.

A try-except clause will not work in this case because the error isn't raised inside the try statement, it's being raised in the invoked command.

Answer (score -1):

This is taking players and using `.split` to make it a list with names them using `split_list` to split it in half.

```py
def split_list(a_list):
    half = len(a_list)//2
    return a_list[:half], a_list[half:]


@client.command()
async def new(ctx, *, players):

    team1, team2 = split_list(players.split())
    response = "Team 1"
    response2 = "Team 2"

    await ctx.send(f'''{response} -- {''.join(team1)}
{response2} -- {''.join(team2)}''')
```

Answer (score -1):

In discord, you never specified the required argument `players`. You can make this not required and show the error message by making the argument have a default param.

```
@client.command()
async def new(ctx, *, players=None):
    if players:
        data = Team()
        data_output = data.team(players)
        team1 = data_output[0]
        team2 = data_output[1]
        response = "Team 1"
        response2 = "Team 2"
        
        await ctx.send(f'''{response} -- {team1}
{response2} -- {team2}''')

    else:
        await ctx.send('''Please use the command in the correct format
First the command by "/new"
and then the name of the players without and thing between
other than spaces

Example: /new p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6''')
```

So then in discord, you can just do this: `/new` and it returns the error.