# I want the bot to send a "no" message if it doesn't have permission. But

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I tried all the methods I knew, but I didn't get any results.
I need help and I just need a solution!

Thanks for help

CMD:

```
discord.app_commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command 'nikname' raised an exception: Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
```

code:

```
from discord.ext.commands import MissingPermissions

@client.tree.command(name='nikname', description='testing the bot')
async def nikname(interaction: discord.Interaction, user: discord.User, *, nickname: str):
    await user.edit(nick=nickname)
    
    if MissingPermissions == True:
        await interaction.response.send_message("no")        
    else:
        await interaction.response.send_message("ok")
```

Comment: Hello. What is "all the methods I knew"? We don't know what you know. Also, does this help? [Try and except function error in a discord bot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64913030/try-and-except-function-error-in-a-discord-bot)

Comment: Does your code throw the error you labeled as CMD? Maybe you should then try with a `try ... except` clause.

Comment: You tell me the solution that you think is correct, maybe it can help @stef

Answer (score 1):

```py
    await user.edit(nick=nickname)
    
    if MissingPermissions == True:
        await interaction.response.send_message("no")        
    else:
        await interaction.response.send_message("ok")
```

This code doesn't make any sense. You may want to read up on what `Exceptions` are and how they work: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

`User.edit` raises the exception, so you have to catch it. Anything below `user.edit()` is already too late, your code has crashed & that function has stopped executing.

Comment: Unfortunately, using `try`/`except` inside a discord bot command typically doesn't work either. The discord api has its own error-handling methods.

Comment: @Stef that's very wrong. Those methods don't get triggered if you catch the exception directly yourself. That's how exceptions work. Dpy's error handlers won't do anything if you stop the error from propagating.